# Как передать значение из javascript в Controller c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#, mvc, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Пишу на `asp.net mvc + dojo`.
Есть комбобокс. При выборе элемента из него нужно получить его `ID`. Получаю это через следующую функцию.

```
var comboBox1 = new ComboBox({
    id:"inputKor",
    name:"inputKor",
    value:"",
    store:store,
    searchAttr:"name",
    onChange:function() {
        var selItem1 = comboBox1.store.getValue(comboBox1.item, "id");
        alert(selItem1.toString());
    }
});
```

Вот так отправляю данные в контроллер

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewDoc_", "Index"))
{
    ...
    <button type="submit" id="btnAdd" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" style="margin-left: 40%;
        margin-top: 5px;">
        Добавить</button>
}
```

Как мне передать из функции значение `selItem1` в контроллер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Это в скрипте

```
document.getElementById("selItemQ").value=selItem;
```

А это в передаче данных

```
<input type="hidden" name="selItem1" id="selItemQ"/>
```